# redirect() function not working in Codeigniter 2.0

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /abc_dev/   
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is my config.php:

```
$server_protocol        = 'http://'; 
$application_name       = '';
$website_fullpath       = $server_protocol.$website_path;
$application_path       = str_replace(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']),'',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$application_fullpath   = $server_protocol.$application_path;
$config['base_url'] = $application_fullpath;  
$config['log_threshold'] = 0;
```

This is my construct function:

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();  
    $this->load->model('Modelhome');        
    $this->load->library('nsession');
    $this->controller = 'home';
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->helper('string');
}
```

This is my logout function:

```
function logout(){
    $this->nsession->destroy();
    redirect(base_url());
}
```

In case of logout redirect(base_url()) not working in server. 
Url becomes http://example.com/abc_dev/home/logout . It remains the same and page becomes white. Can anyone tell me what is the problem?

Comment: What is nsession are you sure its should be session

Comment: enable  error reporting and see if any error is occuring

Answer (score 0):

just give your index or home page controller in redirect

```
redirect('c_home',refresh);
```

Comment: No, not working.
It goes to http://example.com/abc_dev/home/logout/ with a white page

Comment: $config['base_url'] = '';  Set this